# Android Jni непонятки с C массивом

Tags: android, c, массивы, native

Необходимо `string` массив перевести в `char*`.Получаю массив из `java` типа `String`.Далее в цикле заполняю `char*` массив.Положил элемент вывел лог там лежит что нужно.После окончания цикла вывожу элементы `char*` массива и все они равны последнему элементу `java` массива.Не пойму что происходит.Как это исправить?

`Android C`

```
char* param[3];
int resArrayCount = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env,resArray);

for(int i = 0; i < resArrayCount; i++) {
    jstring string = (jstring) (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env,resArray, i);
    const char* name = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,string, JNI_FALSE);
    param[i] = name;
    ALOG("%s",param[i]);//То что положил то и лежит
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env,string, name);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env,string);
}

    ALOG("%s",param[0]);//Последний элемент
    ALOG("%s",param[1]);//Последний элемент
    ALOG("%s",param[2]);//Последний элемент
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все логично. Открываем [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) и читаем

> Returns a pointer to an array of bytes representing the string in modified UTF-8 encoding. This array is valid until it is released by ReleaseStringUTFChars().

То есть, указатель то получили, но следующими строками его и почистили и указатель показывает в никуда. Добро пожаловать в мир с/с++, в мир, где можно выстрелить себе в ногу и не заметить.

Что делать - строку себе нужно скопировать. Скорее всего поможет strdup

```
param[i] = strdup(name);
```

И так как GC нет, некому подчищать, то нужно будет ручками почистить

```
for(int i = 0; i < resArrayCount; i++) {
  free(param[i]);
}
```

Comment: Бытует мнение что после GetStringUTFChars нужно вызвать ReleaseStringUTFChars да бы освободить память я так и сделал.я думал присвоил значит скопировал.про free знаю но массив будет глобальный.зачем free(param[i]) когда можно free(param)?я бы сказал и в мир android java там то же иногда непонятки конкретные.

Comment: Вы копируете, но не данные, а указатели. `free(param[i])` нужен, потому что есть массив строк - каждую нужно отдельно освобождать. `free(param)` сделает совсем не то (скорее всего упадет)

Comment: Еще можно strcp.во в java как все просто.а тут все чистить нужно.массив глобальный лучше создать допустим 1 длины а потом увеличить память.или где нужно и сделать newglobalref?хотел чистить все в jni_onunload но беда она никогда не вызывается.

Comment: наверно можно не вызывать ReleaseStringUTFChars и проблем не будет

Comment: ReleaseStringUTFChars нужно вызывать, когда уже не нужна строка. Но нужно как всегда быть аккуратным. А вот с деструкторами (финализаторами) в java всегда была беда - когда они будут вызваны, одному gc известно.

Comment: jni_onload работает исправно.так не получится.или потом в цикле вертеть ReleaseStringUTFChars